# Spring JAAS Authentication with Weblogic

Tags: java, spring-mvc, weblogic12c

I have developed a shoppingcart app using Spring mvc.I am using weblogic-12.2.1 for deployment.I have created users and roles in weblogic and also configure an application specific realm in weblogic.Now for implementing JAAS authentication
I have done the following things in `web.xml`

```
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
   </security-constraint>
   <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <realm-name>shoppingcartRealm</realm-name>
      <form-login-config>
          <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/view/login.jsp</form-login-page>
          <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/view/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
  <security-role>
      <role-name>*</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

Now I want to know how to redirect login page at application startup??

I have a `<welcome-file>` configured as below:

```
 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

In my `welcome.jsp`  I cannot just redirect to login page like below:

```
<%
  response.sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp");
 %>
```

Because I know in spring-mvc it won't work like this.
so,How can I make my Application to support JAAS Authentication?

Comment: Let your application pickup the resource that you can't access.

Comment: I didn't get ur logic

Comment: You can write a servlet or use any other framework that is doing forwarding of Struts request to the action result which is being executed.